# Google drive authentication using phonegap

Tags: google-drive-api

i want to authenticate the Google Drive (Google docs) using java script in phonegap.Please give me any suggestions

Comment: This was a perfectly obvious question, not sure why you closed it.

Comment: did you get this to work with phonegap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the client side flow:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent

Comment: Hi  @Ali Afshar I have seen your tutorial regarding google drive ,I have tried to implement it in my phonegap application "https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-js" But fail to do so But its working perfectly in browser in Device i am  Getting the issue " X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'  kindly let me know if you can help me out.....Thanks